# DateTime.ParseExact throws a string format error Unity3D

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine, datetime-format

I've been trying to use DateTime.ParseExact to read DateTime information I receive from a database. The received data is in string format and looks like this

```
"00:10:47:18"
```

The code I am implementing is as follows:

```
D = DateTime.ParseExact("00:10:47:18", "dd:HH:mm:ss", null);
```

Where D is of type DateTime. However, I get a Format Exception saying Invalid String Format. I've also tried doing this

```
D = DateTime.ParseExact("00:10:47:18", "'dd':'HH':'mm':'ss'", null);
```

But even using the above code gives me format exception. Any help in pointing me to the right direction would be appreciated. Note: I am doing this in Unity3D and coding on C#.

Comment: I think it's not valid because you put 'dd' for 00, which means day 0, there are no day 0 on C# i think. Are you really sure "00:10:47:18" is Day : Hour : Minute : Second?

Comment: Hey Vincent, I'm sure its Day:Hour:Minute:Second but I'm not sure if sending a day value as 0 would be a problem. So this date time that I receive is going to set a countdown timer in the game

Comment: So for countdown, what you need is TimeSpan, not DateTime, it's similar, but different.

Comment: I just read up about datetime and issues with passing date as 0. I'm now going to try and receive the data as total hours: minutes: seconds and parse it as a TimeSpan in unity. I will report here if that solves my problem

Comment: Does the database have other options for sending the date?

Comment: To all those who responded to my question, thanks a ton for all the help and advice. I decided to use Vincent's suggestion and use TimeSpan instead of DateTime for my application. I am now reading total seconds from the backend and using TimeSpan.FromSeconds() to solve my problem. Thanks again for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i get from : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992370(v=vs.110).aspx

```
intervalString = "17:14:48.153";
format = "G";
culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
interval = TimeSpan.ParseExact(intervalString, format, culture);
//Console.WriteLine("'{0}' --> {1}", intervalString, interval);
```

**EDIT** for Timespan.Parse from :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx

```
string value = "6:12:14:45";
string cultureName = "en-US";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(value);
//Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1}", value, ts.ToString("c"));
```

Comment: So in Unity I can only do TimeSpan.Parse which takes a string as argument. ParseExact doesn't exist in .Net 4. When i try TimeSpan.Parse(intervalString) I again get format exception

Comment: Hey Vincent, I couldn't really implement any of the suggestions listed for this question but found your input on TimeSpan instead of DateTime to be very helpful for my project. I have solved my problem by using TimeSpan.FromSeconds() instead of parsing the previous format I was receiving. Thanks for helping me understand why TimeSpan would have suited my needs better. I'm marking your response as the answer

Answer (score 3):

Your data looks like duration, not date/time. You have to use TimeSpan for that purpose

```
string input = "00:10:47:18";
TimeSpan output = TimeSpan.ParseExact(input, @"dd\:hh\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Unity doesn't support TimeSpan.ParseExact method (it was introduced in .NET 4), so I guess the only way you can do is manual parsing:

```
public static TimeSpan ParseDuration(string input)
{
    string[] inputParts = input.Split(':');
    string ddString = inputParts[0];
    string hhString = inputParts[1];
    string mmString = inputParts[2];
    string ssString = inputParts[3];
    int dd = int.Parse(ddString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    int hh = int.Parse(hhString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    int mm = int.Parse(mmString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    int ss = int.Parse(ssString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return new TimeSpan(dd, hh, mm, ss);
}
```

Usage:

```
string input = "00:10:47:18";
TimeSpan output = ParseDuration(input);
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for your response. Let me try that and get back to you

Comment: I tried to parse it as a TimeSpan but I can't use ParseExact from timespans in Unity. I could only do TimeSpan.Parse which took my input string as an argument. Still get a format exception error :/

Comment: @PronayPeddiraju What version of Unity do you use?

Comment: I'm using 2017.3.1p3

Comment: @PronayPeddiraju I guess you are left with manual parsing, I've added sample code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time out to provide that sample code. I however decided to retrieve only the total seconds from the backend and use TimeSpan.FromSeconds() to get the required data. Thanks again for the help though